# How should I use 'no longer' in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

What is the correct (or at least the most natural) way to say this?

> There is no longer any conflict...

or

> No longer there is any conflict...

Comment: The first one is best. The second is incorrect but could be made acceptable by swapping the words "there" and "is": "No longer is there any conflict". However, this is a more archaic word order that would not normally be used, so it would make you sound odd and overly formal. The first option: "There is no longer any conflict" is what most native speakers would use.

Comment: Grammatically speaking, only the first sentence is correct. It is easily understandable. However, I must say, you can use the second variation if you are writing a poem, because poems usually do not abide by the English grammar rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is best. The second is incorrect but could be made acceptable by swapping the words "there" and "is":

> "No longer is there any conflict".

However, this is a more archaic word order that would not normally be used, so it would make you sound odd and overly formal. The first option: "There is no longer any conflict" is what most native speakers would use.   -- MarielS